# Data access from a member function of different classes in C++

Tags: c++

I am confused how to implement data member access from a different class.
I have three classes in three different header files.

```
A.h
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
class A{

    B *b;
    friend void dataaccess_b_from_class_A(int a);
}

B.h
class B{

}

C.h
class C{

   void dataaccess_b_from_class_A(int a);
}
void C::dataaccess_b_from_class_A(int a)
{
   b = new B(); //I got error as symbol b could not be resolved.
}
```

I like `dataaccess_b_from_class_A()` method from `class C` access data `B *b` from `Class A`.
I put friend function inside `class A`, but I got `error as symbol b could not be resolved`.How can I implement it?

EDIT1:
According to the discussion 'gmas80',
what I did was

```
class B; // forward declaration

class A{
public:
    A(){};
private:
    static B* b; // since in the dataaccess_to_class_A you are using new
    friend class C; // this make b and dataaccess_from_class_C accessible
};

class B{
public:
    B(){ cout << "B" << endl; };
   // add content
};

class C{
public: // you need this keyword if you want to call this function from outside
   void dataaccess_to_class_A(A a);
};

void C::dataaccess_to_class_A(A a)
{
   A::b = new B(); //Error as undefined reference to class A::b

   cout << "C" << endl; // test if called
}
```

If I don't include static, I got b `could not be resolved`.
If I include static, I got `undefined reference`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included so many mistakes in a so small piece of code! why don't you start simpler? Here a modified single-file version of your code that compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B; // forward declaration

class A{
public:
    A(){};
private:
    B* b; // since in the dataaccess_to_class_A you are using new
    void dataaccess_from_class_C(){ cout << "A" << endl; }; // test if called
    friend class C; // this make b and dataaccess_from_class_C accessible
};

class B{
public:
    B(){ cout << "B" << endl; };
   // add content
};

class C{
public: // you need this keyword if you want to call this function from outside
   void dataaccess_to_class_A(A a);
};

void C::dataaccess_to_class_A(A a)
{
   a.b = new B(); // this is a potentially memory leak if you will not delete in somehow
   a.dataaccess_from_class_C();
   cout << "C" << endl; // test if called
}

// it is better if you post runnable code
int main() {
    C c;
    A a;
    c.dataaccess_to_class_A(a);
}
```

**AFTER EDIT1**

Now you can start to move the class in a header file, but you need to add guardians to avoid multiple definitions..

*a.h*

```
#ifndef H_GUARDIAN_A
#define H_GUARDIAN_A

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B; // forward declaration

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {};
private:
    B* b; // since in the dataaccess_to_class_A you are using new
    void dataaccess_from_class_C()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }; // test if called
    friend class C; // this make b and dataaccess_from_class_C accessible
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    };
    // add content
};

class C
{
public: // you need this keyword if you want to call this function from outside
    void dataaccess_to_class_A( A a );
};

void C::dataaccess_to_class_A( A a )
{
    a.b = new B(); // this is a potentially memory leak if you will not delete in somehow
    a.dataaccess_from_class_C();
    cout << "C" << endl; // test if called
}

#endif
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "a.h"

// it is better if you post runnable code
int main()
{
    C c;
    A a;
    c.dataaccess_to_class_A( a );
}
```

Does it make sense for you? I simple moved the class declarations in another file that is included..

**EDIT2**

Now we split the class definitions in three different headers..

*a.h*

```
#ifndef H_GUARDIAN_A
#define H_GUARDIAN_A

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(): b(NULL){}; // initialize to NULL the b pointer
    ~A(); // new entry: destructor to eventually delete b (only member function declaration)
private:
    B* b; // since in the dataaccess_to_class_A you are using new
    void dataaccess_from_class_C()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl; // test if called
    }; 
    friend class C; // this make b and dataaccess_from_class_C accessible
};

#endif
```

*a.cpp* // new entry! it avoids circular dependency.. the destructor is defined here

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

A::~A() // destructor that eventually clean memory for b
{
    if( b ) delete b;
}
```

*b.h*

```
#ifndef H_GUARDIAN_B
#define H_GUARDIAN_B

#include "a.h"

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    };
    // add content
};

#endif
```

*c.h*

```
#ifndef H_GUARDIAN_C
#define H_GUARDIAN_C

#include "b.h"

class C
{
public: // you need this keyword if you want to call this function from outside

    void dataaccess_to_class_A( A a );
};

void C::dataaccess_to_class_A( A a )
{
    a.b = new B(); // this is a potentially memory leak if you will not delete in somehow
    a.dataaccess_from_class_C();
    cout << "C" << endl; // test if called
}

#endif
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "c.h"

// it is better if you post runnable code
int main()
{
    C c;
    A a;
    c.dataaccess_to_class_A( a );
}
```

Comment: @batuman: does the above make sense? If yes, we can move forward with splitting the classes in 3 headers..

Comment: Ok thanks, now it works. According to the discussion with you, I updated in my EDIT1. But I still need B*  A::b= NULL; in classA's cpp file. If not undefined reference error. Thanks

Comment: @batuman: Look at the *EDIT2*, I was bringing you there! ;) Which compiler are you using? This is another information that you might want to ass in a SO question.. I am testing it with MSVC13 and gcc

Comment: Actually I am compiling for Android, so compile with ndk-build, actually with gcc

Answer (score 0):

add

```
include "B.h"
```

in the beginning if the C.h
and define the type of b

```
B b( new B() );
```

also, specify the fully qualified method in your freind declaration:

```
friend void C::dataaccess_b_from_class_A(int a);
```

include C.h into A.h, 
and do not forget include guards in each header

Another point. Why are you defining C::dataaccess_b_from_class_A in the header? I would suggest to do it  in a separate file. Say, "C.cpp".